# How to view DVI on Mac OS X?

Tags: viewers, dvi

What are some good software to view DVI files on OS X?

Comment: Yes: install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and you can run `xdvi`.

Comment: TeXshop is able to open `.dvi` files (no need to install XQuartz).

Comment: @Guido True, but there is a difference: TeXShop converts them into PDF files before opening them, not xdvi.

Comment: @Guido viewing natively a `dvi` file with `xdvi` has great advantages in terms of speed and responsiveness compared to first converting it to `pdf` format and then use one of those bulky pdf viewers.

Comment: Under MacOS X 10.12.6 with TeXlive 2017, you have to install XQuartz 2.7.11 to run xdvi 22.87.03.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org and you'll be able to run Xdvi:

```
xdvi filename.dvi &
```

from the terminal will do. A full MacTeX (TeX Live) installation is of course required.

[image]

Comment: Installing Xquartz does not seem to install xdvi and/or does not make it available in terminal.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock A TeX distribution is needed. I assumed the OP already had it, but now my answer specifies it.

Comment: I think what's missing is where to find xdvi and/or how to get xdvi on your path, as installing MacTeX does not add anything to the path.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock `which xdvi` on my machine returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/xdvi`. If you are able to run `tex`, then you're also able to run `xdvi`, provided XQuartz is installed.

Answer (score 7):

...and without XQuartz one can use `dvipdfmx filename.dvi` to convert dvi to pdf.

Comment: (my XQuartz stopped working after upgrade to Yosemite, but dvipdfmx still works just fine)

Comment: just reinstall `XQuartz`. See https://tug.org/mactex/yosemite.html for a description of this and other issues of the Yosemite upgrade process

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Skim with good results: http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/

[image: Skim in action on cweb dvi]

Comment: Can Skim really read dvi files??

Comment: @lhf Yes. Added screenshot to answer.

Comment: @qu1j0t3 Actually, it converts the DVI file to PDF.

Comment: Maybe so. Point being that it works fine as a DVI viewer. (I've written DVI viewers. The job *is* to convert DVI to whatever API/interface is convenient for display.)

Comment: It appears that Skim uses dvipdfmx to convert DVI to PDF. So installing Skim by itself is not sufficient to open DVI files (and in fact, if you have dvipdfmx to convert DVI to PDF, then you could use any PDF viewer).